# How to get the custom commit report using git log and unix commands?

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-log, bitbucket-server

I am using the below command to get the commit report for a repository in stash. I am able to get the author name,commit id, date,comments etc in the repository and export to csv files, But unable to get the branch names. I am expecting a report to get the repo name, branch name, commit for the branch, author for the commit, date etc. If possible i want the jira ids with comments also.

```
git log --pretty=format:'"%h","%an","%aD","%s",' --shortstat --no-merges | paste - - - > out.csv
```

Comment: can someone reply please

Comment: can anyone reply please ?

Comment: any problem with my question format ?

Comment: No needs to "ping". You question will be answered once a person who knows the answer will have a willing and free time to do so. When you will have more reputation, you will be able to exchange part of it for [bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty), which makes answering your question more attractive for others. `any problem with my question format?` - Usually, bad questions attracts downvotes or close-votes very fast. Since your question has none of them, no needs to worry.